# List directory contents on Windows in hex or other form that shows the non-ASCII chars in detail

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, encoding

I need to determine the unicode normalization used for specific on-disk file names in Windows 10.

Specifically, I need to see if a file name uses NFC or NFD form for non-ASCII latin characters such as "ü".

In Linux, I can do this:

```
ls | xxd
```

This will show the dir listing as hex bytes.

How do I achieve something similar in Windows? It doesn't have to be hex - any other escaped form is okay as well, e.g. in C string format (such as `u\CC\88`).

It doesn't have to be a built-in command. If you can point me to other programs, that's helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a powershell prompt instead of cmd, you can use

```
ls -name | format-hex
```

or

```
dir -name | format-hex
```

ls and dir are just an aliases for get-childitem.  The actual command would be

```
get-childitem -name | format-hex
```